# Event fires twice with Jasny Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

The following HTML uses [Jasny Bootstrap mod fileinput.js](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput)

```
<div class="profile_image">
            <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/5/update_image" class="edit_user" data-remote="true" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_user_5" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="xx6ELZRrTR6XDzmujIPBsCkr8zbK19I/7CprOOTiblM="></div>
                <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                    <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; position: relative;">
                        <img alt="7bbfd77c 1102 4831 9ba8 246fb67460b3.2014 01 17" class="img-responsive" src="http://myweb.com/image.jpg">
                        <div class="choose_new">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-file">
                            <input id="user_avatar" name="user[avatar]" type="file">

                    </div>
                </div>
                    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

        </div>
```

I want to listen to the change.bs.fileinput event to automatically submit the form once an image is selected

using

```
$(".fileinput").on("change.bs.fileinput", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    alert();
    return false;
});
```

Doing this will result in 2 alerts

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried with  **$('form.edit_user').submit();**?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you manage to find out what was causing it?

Comment: Note that this only happens after adding the bootstrap-spinner.js file to the page (<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/bootstrap-fileinput/bootstrap-fileinput.js"></script> )

Comment: I think this issue resolved itself when fileinput.js got upgraded. I am using v 3.1.3 at the moment

Comment: Aha Niko! After some hours digging...I reached the same conclusion. I'll answer this question accordingly for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the question is related to the fileinput's version. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8ha8o97/) showcasing the issue, using fileinput version 3.0.0-p7 (code below)

If we update the fiddle to version 3.1.3 (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js), then the issue will not manifest itself.

**JSFIDDLE SHOWCASE (with JQuery 1.11.0 and the added resource for fileinput-3.0.0-p7):**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#file-upload').on('change.bs.fileinput', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert("yy");
        console.log(event);
    });
});

<div id="file-upload">
    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
        <span class="btn default btn-file"> <span class="fileinput-new"> SELECT </span> <span class="fileinput-exists"> CHANGE</span> <input id="uploadID"
            type="file" name="upload"> <input type="hidden" id="answerId" value="85009">
        </span> <span class="fileinput-filename"> </span> &nbsp; <a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput" style="float: none"> </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: also note that this issue got reported and solved at v 3.1.1 https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/issues/182

Answer (score 1):

You can submit a form with the "submit" event instead triggering a "click".

```
$(".fileinput").on("change.bs.fileinput", function(){
       $("#edit_user_5").submit();
       return false;
}
```